# Should I use two ViewModels(one SharedViewModel scoped to NavGraphs, another ActivityViewModel scoped to Activity) in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I'm working on a project that uses multiple **Fragments and single Activity**. Some of the Fragments that have similar behavior has a `Shared ViewModel scoped to individual Nested NavGraphs`. But at the start of the activity, all Fragments needs to check `one common property(internet connection livedata)` present in **Activity ViewModel**. Now since the start of the app, all fragments require to check `Internet Connection LiveData` which is present within the `ActivityViewModel`, how should I pass the **LiveData** or the **ActivityViewModel instance** to individual Fragments? I tried using a `Single ViewModel scoped to Activity for all fragments` but doing that way will make the **ViewModel** complex. **How should I solve the problem?**.  Should I get the `instance of ActivityViewModel` inside each Fragment? But doing these will result my fragment to have `two Viewmodels- one from Activty another from Navgraph`. What should I do? What is the recommended approach?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't  see a problem with having two view Models in fragment . `Internet Connection LiveData` is just one use case . What if you want to keep some data even after fragment is detached and when attached again use the same data without calling the data source.. Thats when Activity's ViewModel come to play.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. But some say **google's recommended approach is single ViewModel per view**. That is why this question

Comment: Its Still the Single `ViewModel` because the other one is shared and bind to Activity's lifecycle not Fragment's .